# How to get window object output in console using 'this' keyword in standalone function call

Tags: javascript, class, object, ecmascript-6, this

I want to check how 'this' keyword is behaving in Javascript ES6. To perform this I wrote code snippets to check output of 'this' keyword in object and also normal standalone function.

When I call the draw() method, It gives an error. I want to prove, when calling draw() method, output will be **Window.object.**

What is wrong in my code?

```js
const Circle = function(){ //constructor
    this.draw = function(){
        console.log(this);
    }
};

const c = new Circle();
c.draw(); //output => above object
console.log(c.draw); //output => draw function

draw();
```

Comment: The error is fired beacuse you haven't declared `draw` function, it's only live in the instances of `Circle`.

Comment: So `const draw = c.draw;`?